# Linux PPTP VPN and gateway woes

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, nat, pptp

I have an Amazon Linux machine running in an Amazon EC2 instance.

I am connecting to my office's VPN as follows:

```
sudo pppd pty "pptp pptp.<DOMAIN>.com --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 2 --debug" file /etc/ppp/options.pptp user <MYUSER> password <MYPASS>
```

I can see in `/var/log/messages` that I am connecting:

```
CHAP authentication succeeded
```

But when I ping a server located within the remote network it just hangs:

```
ping -I ppp0 newdev.<DOMAIN>.com
```

I can ping the machine without -I, but I get its external IP address:

```
ping newdev.<DOMAIN>.com
PING devserver.<DOMAIN>.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=109 time=15.5 ms
64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=109 time=15.4 ms
64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=3 ttl=109 time=14.5 ms
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, I'm just not sure what.

Routing table when connected:

```
Kernel IP routing table 
Destination      Gateway       Genmask         Flags MSS Window irtt Iface
192.168.6.108    0.0.0.0       255.255.255.255 UH 0 0 0              ppp0 
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  xxx.xxx.xxx.1 255.255.255.255 UGH 0 0 0             eth0 
xxx.xxx.xxx.0    0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0   U 0 0 0               eth0 
0.0.0.0          xxx.xxx.xxx.1 0.0.0.0         UG 0 0 0              eth0
```

Comment: If newdev.<DOMAIN>.com resolves to the external address, then I'd expect this behavior.  Can you ping its internal address with -I?

Comment: No, the same thing happens.  It just hangs.

If I connect to the same VPN from Windows 7 (and default gateway disabled) it resolves to the internal ip.

Comment: I meant IP address - are you saying ping hangs when you ping the internal IP address?

Comment: Yes, so the internal ip is 192.168.7.7.  If I ping that  it just hangs.

Comment: Are you able to post `netstat -rn` when connected?  Santise if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The 192.168.7.0/24 network is not routed via ppp0

```
route add -net 192.168.7.0/24 gw 0.0.0.0 ppp0
```

Comment: Now I get  `route: netmask 000000ff doesn't make sense with host route`

Comment: My mistake, I missed a switch - answer updated