# Why does my PPTP VPN connection fail to route to the remote network in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, pptp

I'm trying to connect to my office's PPTP VPN on Linux via `ppp`.  The gateway has a local IP address in the `10.4.x.x` net and I need to access other machines in the `10.x.x.x` net (which I can do normally from the office).  Colleagues can connect and use the VPN via their Apple computers, but only after making it the first network service in the list.  I'm able to connect and get a `10.4.zzz.zzz` IP address on `ppp0`, but I cannot get a response from inside the remote network, either from `ping` or by trying to `ssh` into one of the machines.

In my `/etc/peers/office`:

```
pty "pptp pptp.<DOMAIN>.com --nolaunchpppd"
name <USER>
remotename PPTP
require-mppe-128
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
ipparam office
```

Issuing `pon office debug dump logfd 2 nodetach` then appears successful:

```
pppd options in effect:
debug       # (from command line)
nodetach        # (from command line)
logfd 2     # (from command line)
dump        # (from command line)
noauth      # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
refuse-pap      # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
refuse-chap     # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
refuse-mschap       # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
refuse-eap      # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
name <USER>     # (from /etc/ppp/peers/office)
remotename PPTP     # (from /etc/ppp/peers/office)
        # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
pty pptp pptp.<DOMAIN>.com --nolaunchpppd       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/office)
ipparam office      # (from /etc/ppp/peers/office)
nobsdcomp       # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
nodeflate       # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
require-mppe-128        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/office)
using channel 2
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/0
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x15814c2c> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0xd <accomp> <pcomp> <mru 1500> <magic 0x33c6e738> <auth chap MS-v2> <mrru 1600> <ssnhf> <endpoint [MAC:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX]>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0xd <mrru 1600> <ssnhf>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x15814c2c> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0xe <accomp> <pcomp> <mru 1500> <magic 0x33c6e738> <auth chap MS-v2>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0xe <accomp> <pcomp> <mru 1500> <magic 0x33c6e738> <auth chap MS-v2>]
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1 <bb1e6894d1b6ef95af9a9c20b624e082>, name = ""]
added response cache entry 0
sent [CHAP Response id=0x1 <fabc6b0fce7e78f50a3822b482bb5127000000000000000030f78cf80000cdb449af8a264f1e417ad9c4b45b6bf37dbf00>, name = "<USER>"]
rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x1 "S=7D6A4E8B637EE57C21CC5800CBB4BF7B235C0799"]
response found in cache (entry 0)
CHAP authentication succeeded
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xd6 <addr 10.4.xxx.xxx> <compress VJ 0f 00>]
sent [IPCP TermAck id=0xd6]
rcvd [CCP ConfReq id=0x76 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
sent [CCP ConfAck id=0x76 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
rcvd [CCP ConfAck id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr 10.4.zzz.zzz>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.4.zzz.zzz>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 10.4.zzz.zzz>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xd7 <addr 10.4.xxx.xxx> <compress VJ 0f 00>]
sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0xd7 <addr 10.4.xxx.xxx> <compress VJ 0f 00>]
local  IP address 10.4.zzz.zzz
remote IP address 10.4.xxx.xxx
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up started (pid 13333)
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up finished (pid 13333), status = 0x0
```

I've tried adapting [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/360085/126196), since it seems like a similar problem, but to no avail.  It seems promising, though, because as soon as I add the route entry `wireshark` begins to show packets being transmitted on `ppp0`.  However, I see no incoming traffic.  This problem still occurs with `defaultroute` in `/etc/peers/office`.

```
$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         198.18.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp3s0
10.4.xxx.xxx    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 198.18.0.1      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlp3s0
198.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlp3s0

$ route add -net 10.0.0.0 ppp0 netmask 255.0.0.0

$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         198.18.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp3s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 ppp0
10.4.xxx.xxx    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 198.18.0.1      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlp3s0
198.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
```

where the third and fourth entries, respectively, are the public IP address of the office gateway.  What is the wrong network configuration?  Why can I not receive incoming packets?  If these can be resolved, how can `ppp` be configured to take the proper steps automatically.

Comment: Try adding `defaultroute` to the peers file and also check if your firewall isn't interfering.

Comment: @Jan - No effect on the final result and I've added a comment to the original question stating this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may have been a firewall issue.  The `defaultroute` option did end up helping in the end.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Can you expand your answer at all to provide any further information that may be helpful to others with a similar problem?

Comment: @fixer1234 Unfortunately my sysadmin only told me the firewall was recently updated/reconfigured and that I may have had the wrong address. So it might've completely been an issue on the server.